# unable to access newly attached network interface ip on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have attached not in use network interface to ec2 instance, now I have 2 private ip addresses IP0 and IP1 corresponding to eth0 and eth1. 
but I am not able to access the ec2 server through IP1 of eth1 which is newly assigned. how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are able to log in through IP0 (Private IP of eth0) but not with IP1 (Private IP of eth1).

This is due to **Security group** issue

Attached the **Security group** of **eth0** to **eth1** and try to log-in.

Even if you are not able to log in through IP0 (Private IP of eth0) then try with Public I.P attached to eth0 with a valid **inbound security group rule**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am able to login with IP0, and both interface has same security group

Comment: @TKar Can you please share a screenshot of security group attached to both the NIC cards so that I can give you better solution:-)

Comment: found that I need to add secondary IP address into network interface on the box to access as suggested by this post : http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fflummox-engineering.blogspot.com%2F2014%2F01%2Fadd-multiple-private-ip-addresses-to.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEGtDrNG-2HAI24zKta7qiyBSH0_A